# Use libgfrotran.so.3 and GFORTRAN_1.0 on fedora 27

Tags: fedora, gcc, ln, fortran

I am trying to use `fortran` code called [SAMMY-8](http://www.oecd-nea.org/tools/abstract/detail/psr-0158/) which has its binary ready for use.

I was using without any issue while I had `f25` installed. When upgrading to `f27` I got the following error when trying to run the software

> ```
> sammy: error while loading shared libraries: libgfortran.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
> ```

At first I though of making a soft link to `libgfortran.so.4` by using

`ln -s /usr/lib/libgfortran.so.4 /usr/lib/libgfortran.so.3`

but when trying to run the code I got

> ```
> sammy: /lib64/libgfortran.so.3: version `GFORTRAN_1.0' not found (required by sammy) 
> sammy: /lib64/libgfortran.so.3: version `GFORTRAN_1.4' not found (required by sammy)
> ```

I also tried to install `gcc-4.9.2` by installing the following rpm files

- `devtoolset-3-gcc-4.9.2-6.2.el7.x86_64.rpm`
- `devtoolset-3-gcc-c++-4.9.2-6.2.el7.x86_64.rpm`
- `devtoolset-3-libstdc++-devel-4.9.2-6.2.el7.x86_64.rpm`
- `devtoolset-3-runtime-3.1-12.el7.x86_64.rpm`

The installation was successful so I typed `scl enable devtoolset-3 bash` in order to be able to use `gcc-4.9.2` and then run `SAMMY` again, but I still get

> ```
> sammy: /lib64/libgfortran.so.3: version `GFORTRAN_1.0' not found (required by sammy)
> sammy: /lib64/libgfortran.so.3: version `GFORTRAN_1.4' not found (required by sammy)
> ```

Any idea on how to `GFORTRAN_1.0` and `GFORTRAN_1.4` on `f27`?

Comment: What does `rpm -qf /lib64/libgfortran.so.3` output? Did you create your symlink in `/usr/lib64` or `/usr/lib`?

Comment: You should rebuild it from source (which should be present on the CD you received). The included binary is for very old Linux distributions.

Comment: @StephenKitt : Thank you very much for your comment! The output is `file /lib64/libgfortran.so.3 is not owned by any package` and in fact I created a symlink in both `lib` and `lib64`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`libgfortran.so.3` from Fedora 9 : provides.log →

```
libgfortran.so.3(GFORTRAN_1.0)(64bit)    
libgfortran = 4.3.0-8
```

The original package libgfortran-4.3.0-8.x86_64.rpm will conflict, if any fortran dependent applications are installed (e.g. 'openblas-thread'), so a rebuild to a new name is required.

`compat-libgfortran-4.3.0-8.fc27.x86_64.rpm` installs with no issues. Link → https://drive.google.com/file/d/18uMtX2n4-bwM2V2TfOl-w_Fk8t6YSlsk/view?usp=sharing

Install: `# cd Downloads/ && yum install ./compat-libgfortran-4.3.0-8.fc27.x86_64.rpm`

P.S.: The objects `GFORTRAN_1.0), GFORTRAN_1.4)` are also present in later versions, till v.6.x : Fedora 24 → v. 6.3.1 ,

"compat" package = `compat-libgfortran-6.3.1-1.fc27.x86_64.rpm` : Updates the previous installed compat-libgfortran. Link https://drive.google.com/file/d/1f9nPFjuMBGg1XIza_Ajokkm_d7VYmF0_/view?usp=sharing

---

> describe how you built the renamed packages

Write a new spec file ( I used `pkgtool2` to create `compat-libgfortran.spec` https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7S255p3kFXNQ0ZEbHB1V1BUa0E/view?usp=sharing )

```
Summary:   None
Name:      compat-libgfortran
Version:   6.3.1
Release:   1.fc27
License:   GPL
Group:     None          
Packager:  Jerry Donut <jerry@donut.com>
BuildArchitectures: x86_64
BuildRoot:

%description
No description

%files
/usr/lib64/libgfortran.so.3
/usr/lib64/libgfortran.so.3.0.0
```

Copy compat-libgfortran.spec to `/home/[name]/rpms/SPECS/` https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/need-rpm-package-for-php-version-5-2-7-and-up-on-redhat-5-1-a-766486/#13 ... and run `$ rpmbuild -bb compat-libgfortran.spec`

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I think it's partially solved because now when I run the code I get only this error `sammy: /lib64/libgfortran.so.3: version `GFORTRAN_1.4' not found (required by sammy)` so I somehow need `GFORTRAN_1.4`. Any idea?

Comment: I also don't get your P.S. Can you please explain? Thanks in advance!!

Comment: 1. Please see my edited answer : the "P.S". ... 2. We will give it another try : version 6.x → I will add the package to the answer.

Comment: Thank you very much! I'll be waiting for the other package!

Comment: Done : compat-libgfortran-6.3.1-1.fc27.x86_64.rpm, see the answer.

Comment: I would like to ask if it's possible to extend the answer a bit, and describe how you built the renamed packages! Thanks in advance!